# How to get rid of shortcodes in post content once and for all

Tags: posts, shortcode, content, sanitization

I changed theme/plugin now the post content still display shortcodes.

There are some tips around on hiding them, but everytime I use some content functions, the shortcodes shows up again. Also, my shortcodes are the "extended type" such `[theshortcode id="34877"]`, `[theshort size="large" "tiny"]` etc so the tips on removing them from database doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please backup your database before trying**

In your current theme, open the `functions.php` file and add the code below. In `theshortcodeyouhate` inform the shortcode you want to get rid of, note that even extended types works nicely!

Once you added this code, hit F5 and you are done.

```
add_action ('init','remove_shortcode_from_db'); //you can choose any other actions such wp_head etc

function remove_shortcode_from_db($shortcode = 'theshortcodeyouhate') {

global $wpdb;

$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,post_title,post_content FROM
$wpdb->posts");
$regex =
'/\[(\[?)('.$shortcode.')\b([^\]\/]*(?:\/(?!\])[^\]\/]*)*?)(?:(\/)\]|\](?:([
^\[]*+(?:\[(?!\/\2\])[^\[]*+)*+)\[\/\2\])?)(\]?)/s';

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $final = preg_replace($regex,'',$post->post_content);
    $change = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array('post_content' =>
$final), array('ID' => $post->ID));
}
}
```

*Thanks to wp-hackers mailing list*

Comment: Hi Diana, it sounds like you solved the problem, so you should mark this as the accepted answer.